# Word - Missing Pages, but word count still there

Tags: microsoft-word

I opened my word document, which contained about 7 - 8 pages, but now it only shows one page. The page counter says *Page 1 of 2*, while only one page is visible. The word count seems to have everything, it shows 983 words. The document had about 90 images, only two are visible.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? How can I restore my document?

My previous files folder is empty.

[image: Image of Problem]

--------------------------**Suggestion 1:** ---------------------------

Under View > Web Layout

I get my tables and words to appear! That's a good sign, but my images are not present. Is there a way to see if the objects (images) are still present on the document? It opens and closes slowly (as if the file still contains 40 images).

Here's an [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McjNV.png)

Any Thoughts?

--------------------------**Suggestion 2:** ---------------------------

I used the navigation panel to see *Find: Graphics* and sure enough, there were all 91 images listed, but still only two pages listed (with only a single page visible).

Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FEvn.png) showing this

Amy thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem. In the end, I managed to save all the work I had done including: text, tables, and importantly images.

Here's my solution steps:

1) Open the broken document.

[image]

2) Go to View > Web Layout .

[image]

3) Ctrl + A (Select All items on document).

[image]

4) Open a new Document.

[image]

5) Right Click, choose paste Keep Source Formatting.

[image]

6) Save the new document.

[image]

If anyone encounters a similar bug, hopefully, these steps work for them as well.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I did encounter this issue before, and as with your case, my document had a lot of tables. I assumed the document was corrupted, but after rebooting and reopening the document, the issue resolved.  I would suggest that as a first step if you haven't tried that.

Another thing to try: save the document in another format, e.g. .doc, if it's currently a .docx.  See if that recovers your data.  Such issues seem to crop up when the document is from another version of word or, especially (in my experience) when it's been created using Office for Mac.

If this does not work, here is another source to try. I think you are experiencing the issue described in this thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-only-displays-the-first-page-of-doc-files/98c6ef79-70fd-482d-93e0-4ed71bfe04a9

It's still an open issue so hopefully it will be resolved soon: there are a number of suggestions in here that worked for other users. Please advise if any of these work for you!

Comment: I will give both of these a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those did the trick. Still a single page is visible.

Comment: Wow, this is a tricky one.  I think you are experiencing the issue described in this thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-only-displays-the-first-page-of-doc-files/98c6ef79-70fd-482d-93e0-4ed71bfe04a9

It's still an open issue so hopefully it will be resolved soon: there are a number of suggestions in here that worked for other users.  Please advise if any of these work for you!

Comment: This indeed appears to be the same issue. I will look at the solutions there. Thank you for your effort :)

Comment: @TamraRoss I ended up finding a solution. See my answer above.

Comment: @Eggart So glad you were able to save all your data! Word can be such a pain.

Answer (score 0):

After editing a document in Word Online, I had exactly the same problem where all the content was visible in the Web view of Word 2016 but only the first 5 pages were showing in print view.

I found that saving as a DOC restored all of the information to displaying and then was able to save as a DOCX.

Select All and paste into a new document kept giving me the same Web view problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I guess some formatting operation had messed things up, and everything on the page containing the broken object (a group of text boxes and graphs) and after was hidden, with the strange blank space after the last page.

To fix it, I went to the Web Layout as shown in another answer, and then looked around the document until I found the culprit: the group was really tall and very narrow. I deleted it, then Print Layout worked again!

Answer (score 0):

An OUTLINE FIX:  (For my novel of 829 pages with notes, opening it to see it suddenly having only 12 pages!  What the freak--?!)

Following an online search and the above suggested fixes:  I was about to save the .docx as .doc when a small window opened to state the Outline "Collapsed by default" feature would not be saved.

I cancelled the copying process.

Closed everything.

Opened the .docx that seemed to be missing pages, yet seemed to have the correct word count.

Placed cursor in the first Heading 1 paragraph.

In the Home Menu, Styles section, right clicked the box "Heading 1", selected Modify, clicked Format button, clicked Paragraph...

HERE lurks the culprit:  Under Indents and Spacing tab, General section, unchecked "Collapsed by default".  Clicked OK.

Then in the bottom left of my screen, my page count started going back up to 829 pages.  All seemed OK.

Made a normal backup before making any other changes.

Thanks to all the above posters who opened the way to find my fix.

Spread the good Karma all!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue - and what I had to do was 'Accept changes and stop tracking' via the review tab. which seemed to fix the issue. So if your document was using or is using tracked changes, accepting and stop tracking has fixed me issue, all pages are back!

Answer (score 0):

Click on the middle urging next to the zoom slider on the bottom right
Image
You have it on web browser view or whatever it’s called on

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please add more details to your answer, such as screen(s), and don't use terms such as "whatever it's called". You need to be sure that your answer is correct.